# Rotate a scalable and translated SVG element around its center

Tags: svg

I'm trying to rotate paths inside an SVG.

Because rotating in an SVG works different than it does with other html elements via CSS (ie. the default axis in SVG is the element's top left corner instead of its center), I've run into lots of problems.

I need to rotate the paths using their center points as the axis. I can do it by setting transform-origin to 50% 50%, however I also need to translate & scale the paths, and changing the transform-origin fudges the translations.

Pretending the path is a static size, I can do it by including the x/y as half the path's width/height in "rotate(90, x, y)". However, the SVG responsively scales to fit the window size, so the path's width/height is dynamic. (ie. if I set the location for the axis of rotation correctly at a given size, it warps more and more incorrectly as the window changes size. I didn't find a way to do this using percentages-- please tell me if you're aware of a way!)

I think I'm probably missing something incredibly simple but I've floundered on figuring it out myself. How do I rotate these paths-- dynamically sized paths with translations-- using their center as the axis?

(I also experimented applying some of the transforms to a parent  element, but this only resulted in the path clipping)

*The basic problem:*

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2000 2000">
        <g>
        <path class="A" transform="translate(1000 1000) rotate(0) scale(20)" d="m23.5,2 16.5,14.3-16.5,14.3v-6.8h-15v-15h15v-6.8z" d="m23.5,2 16.5,14.3-16.5,14.3v-6.8h-15v-15h15v-6.8z"/>
        <path class="B" transform="translate(1000 1000) rotate(45) scale(20)" d="m23.5,2 16.5,14.3-16.5,14.3v-6.8h-15v-15h15v-6.8z" d="m23.5,2 16.5,14.3-16.5,14.3v-6.8h-15v-15h15v-6.8z"/>
        <path class="C" transform="translate(1000 1000) rotate(90) scale(20)" d="m23.5,2 16.5,14.3-16.5,14.3v-6.8h-15v-15h15v-6.8z" d="m23.5,2 16.5,14.3-16.5,14.3v-6.8h-15v-15h15v-6.8z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

*I can't get the centers of A, B, and C to share one x/y coordinate while maintaining their translations & responsiveness.*

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the easiest way to do this is to draw the original shapes at the origin, then rotate them, then scale them, then move them into the final position that you want. So change that initial relative m to an absolute M and move the initial drawing point so that the center of the arrow will coincide with the origin. (You need to add the "l" to toggle the rest of the path back to relative draw.)

Transforms are applied in reverse order, so you want your rotate last (applied first) and your translate first (applied last).

(I've added fill-opacity so you can see what's happening a bit better)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 2000 2000">
        <g>
        <path class="A" transform="translate(1000 1000) scale(20) rotate(0)"  d="M 0.75,-14.3 l16.5,14.3-16.5,14.3v-6.8h-15v-15h15v-6.8z" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
        <path class="B" transform="translate(1000 1000) scale(20) rotate(45)" d="M 0.75,-14.3 l16.5,14.3-16.5,14.3v-6.8h-15v-15h15v-6.8z" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
        <path class="C" transform="translate(1000 1000) scale(20) rotate(90)" d="M 0.75,-14.3 l16.5,14.3-16.5,14.3v-6.8h-15v-15h15v-6.8z" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I made the SVGs in Adobe Illustrator. I actually never thought there was a chance of me understanding all the "d=" data (it spans multiple pages on the project). However I only need make the changes to some these relatively simple-looking arrows... I'll have to research this more tomorrow, but if you could let me know-- is my understanding correct that the element's 'origin' is essentially the top-most, left-most point of the element, and that what you did is tell the element to draw itself absolutely half-of-its-x-and-y in relation to its origin?

Comment: I don't fully understand the commands for the d attribute yet, but this is definitely the answer and will 100% work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi JMcFar - that's exactly right. Paths look intimidating - but with some practice they're not that hard to follow. Mozilla has a good intro on path commands. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths